# Storing integer value into pictureboxes

Tags: vb.net

Hey so I'm trying to code my pictures so that all of them store a unique integer, which I will then use elsewhere but I'm really struggling right now to just store a value for them. Here's my code for creating the picture, how do I dedicate a number to each picture, where the first picture contains 1, the second 2 as so forth...
So to test for example when I click a picture, their number is displayed.

```
Private Sub bigpictureloader()
        Dim cardcount As Integer
        Dim cards As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        cards.Add(imageurltxt.Text)

        'Create a placeholder variable
        Dim cardPictureBox As PictureBox

        'Loop through every selected card URL
        For Each url As String In cards
            'Create a new PictureBox
             cardPictureBox = New PictureBox()
            cardPictureBox.Size = New Size(100, 100)
            cardPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
            cardPictureBox.WaitOnLoad = False
            AddHandler cardPictureBox.Click, AddressOf imagehandler
            cardcount = 0


            count += 1
            cardcount = count
            cardPictureBox.Tag = cardcount.ToString
            MsgBox(cardPictureBox.Tag)

            'Add the PictureBox to the Form
            Me.Controls.Add(cardPictureBox)

            If imageurltxt.Text = "" Then
                cardPictureBox = Nothing
            Else

                cardPictureBox.LoadAsync(url)
                TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cardPictureBox, 0, 0)
                cardcount = 0
' this is what I tried but I can't get the image to store the cardcount
                count += 1
                cardcount = count
                MsgBox(cardcount)
            End If
            'Load the image asynchronously
            ' cardPictureBox.LoadAsync(url)
            'TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(cardPictureBox, 0, 0)
        Next

    End Sub
```

This is the code for the event of clicking the picture, how do I transfer the cardcount?

```
'Can't seem to transfer the cardcount to here
' tried cardpicturebox instead of sender but it still doesn't transfer cardcount
 Private Sub imagehandler(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        bigpictureloader()
        testdelete()


    End Sub
```

Comment: You could assign the number to the `Tag` of each `PictureBox`. You could even create your own class that inherits `PictureBox` and add your own dedicated property of type `Integer`, then use that type instead of `PictureBox`. Alternatively, just add the `PictureBoxes` to an array and use the indexes as the numbers.

Comment: what's easiest?

Comment: wait I put  this in the bigpictureloader() count += 1
            cardcount = count
            cardPictureBox.Tag = cardcount.ToString
            MsgBox(cardPictureBox.Tag) 
how can my imagehandler recognise the cardcount?

Comment: Please don't post long code snippets in comments, especially unformatted. They're all but unreadable. If you need to post additional code, update your question.  That said, the `sender` parameter in ANY event handler is the object that raised the event, so you access the `PictureBox` that was clicked that way and then get its `Tag` property value.

Comment: sorry I did, I tried doing that but it still says that cardcount isn't declared

Comment: Then you did it wrong. If we can;t see what you did then we can't tell you what's wrong with it. Do as i said and update your question with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just to help you with jmcihinney's comments. If it helps, please upvote his comments, as they are sound advice.

Here's a code snippet which creates a custom class inheriting from the PictureBox class. In short, it's a PictureBox with some added features:

```
Class Cards
    Inherits PictureBox

    'This holds the 'Card number' value
    Private _number As Integer

    'This makes the CardNumber Property Public. You can access it from outside, and in the designer
    Public Property CardNumber As Integer
        Get
            Return _number
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _number = value
        End Set
    End Property

    'This is a fake function just to show that you could add custom functions here
    Public Sub FakeSub()
        MessageBox.Show("My card number is: " & _number.ToString)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Using this class instead of the PictureBox, you'll be able to access the Property you set up (I made up one which looked kinda like what you wanted, but I'll leave the details to you) from outside the class (as it's Public). If you create one inside the designer, you'll notice that your Public Properties are showing with the other Properties! Isn't it amazing?

Also, this property being declared as an Integer, you won't have to juggle with conversions. I can answer your questions if you need more explanations.

Have fun!